# Address Normalisation API for desktop Application in JAVA

Tags: java, foursquare, google-geocoding-api, usps, smartystreets

I have address, it is poorly formatted addresses or incomplete addresses or spelling mistakes. I want to get proper address even though. How to find proper address in Java for Web Application (Desktop Application)?

**Note:** API should be free open source. So I can use it in my App.

Ex: Address Name: Ave/Aevnue/Aven

```
Original Name: Avenue
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

[SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) does a good job cleaning up and standardizing street addresses, although it can only fix it if it is an otherwise valid address. You can try out the demo for free [here](https://smartystreets.com/products/single-address).

As far as incomplete addresses, There does need to be enough to tell what the address is supposed to be. For example, `1234 South Oak` is not enough to go off of. You need either the city and state, or the ZIP Code.

The address `1600 amphetheater parkway, mountain view, california` would come out as

`1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy
Mountain View CA 94043-1351`

The misspelling of `Amphitheatre` has been corrected, the ZIP code has been added, and everything now follows the USPS standard format (including proper abbreviations).

SmartyStreets has many [SDKs](https://smartystreets.com/docs/sdk) (including a [Java](https://smartystreets.com/docs/sdk/java) one) to make integration into your code easier. The SDKs are open source and use the Apache 2 license, so you can feel free to use them in any app, even commercial ones.

You can start with a free subscription of 250 lookups per month to try SmartyStreets out, and if you need more than that, larger paid subscriptions are available.

(Full disclosure: I am a software developer for SmartyStreets, and I built the Java SDK)